# how get a list from google endpoint with angular $resource?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to call a list from a google endpoint with $resource, before that I was using http, but with $resource seems more clear.
Is just to fill a combobox.

My service.js looks like:

```
provinciaServices.factory('Provincia', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('https://local.appspot.com/_ah/api/provinciaendpoint/v1/:provinciaId', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{provinciaId:'provincia'}}
    });
  }]);
```

and in my controler I call the list with the following line:

```
$scope.provincias = Provincia.query();
```

Comment: Was the call with $http working? Do you get any errors with $resource?

Comment: I'm not getting errors, and the $http is working but the url is a little bit different, is https://local.appspot.com/_ah/api/provinciaendpoint/v1/provincia

Comment: If I put  query: {method: 'GET', params: {provinciaId: 'provincia'}, isArray:true} I get Error: error:badcfg

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234423/hot-to-return-a-pure-array-of-objects-from-appengine-endpoint

Answer (score 0):

[The recommended way](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications/) to interact with an Endpoints API is through the client library for js. Read that link if you're doing angular with endpoints no matter what - it's a great resource.

You *can* use $http to hit your endpoints API as a REST service, but this requires some careful use of routes and HTTP verbs, and OAuth is a little more difficult, if you feel you might want to do that later.

I'm not really sure what your error with $resource is. Could you update your question perhaps?